# Unable to register EC2 instances with ECS (EC2) cluster using terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

I am unable to register EC2 instances with ECS cluster through terraform by using AWS as provider. I have followed all the links and tried everything but still facing issue. Can any one please assist me in reviewing my code and assist me where am I wrong and why my EC2 instance not registered with ECS cluster?

```
#1. Frontend security group
resource "aws_security_group" "sample_web_sg" {
    name        = "${var.name}-web-sg"
    description = "sample-web-sg"
    vpc_id      = var.vpc_id

    ingress {
        description = "HTTP"
        from_port   = 80
        to_port     = 80
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
    ingress {
        description = "HTTP"
        from_port   = 22
        to_port     = 22
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
    
    egress {
        from_port   = 0
        to_port     = 0
        protocol    = "-1"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }

    tags = {
        Name = "${var.name}-web-sg"
        Environment = var.environment
    }
}

#2. IAM role
resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs-instance-role" {
  name = "ecs-instance-role-test-web-1"
  path = "/"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": ["ecs.amazonaws.com"]
      },
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs-instance-role-attachment" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs-instance-role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role"
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "ecs_service_role" {
  role = aws_iam_role.ecs-instance-role.name
}
#3. Launch Configuration
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "sample_web_server_lc" {
  name          = "sample-web-server-lc"
  image_id      = "ami-08e0b00e3616220d8"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  iam_instance_profile        = aws_iam_instance_profile.ecs_service_role.name
  security_groups   = [aws_security_group.sample_web_sg.id]
  key_name          = "sample-key-us-east-2"
  associate_public_ip_address = "true"
  user_data = <<-EOF
                #!/bin/bash
                sudo yum update -y
                sudo echo "ECS_CLUSTER=my-cluster" >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
                EOF
  }

#4. Autoscaling
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "sample_asg" {
  name                      = "sample-asg"
  max_size                  = 1
  min_size                  = 1
  health_check_grace_period = 300
  desired_capacity          = 1
  launch_configuration      = aws_launch_configuration.sample_web_server_lc.id
  vpc_zone_identifier       = [var.subnet_id]
  health_check_type         = "EC2"
  
}



#5. ECS cluster
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "my-cluster" {
    name = "my-cluster"
    capacity_providers = [aws_ecs_capacity_provider.sample-ecs-capacity-provider.name]
}

#6. ECS task definition
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "sample_ecs_task_definition" {
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["EC2"]
  cpu                      = 1024
  memory                   = 2048
  family                   = "sample_ecs_service"
  container_definitions = <<DEFINITION
[
  {
    "image": "wordpress:latest",
    "cpu": 1024,
    "memory": 512,
    "name": "sample-wordpress-task-definition",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": 80,
        "hostPort": 80
      }
    ]
  }
]
DEFINITION
}

#7. ECS Service
resource "aws_ecs_service" "sample_ecs_service" {
  name            = "sample_ecs_service"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.my-cluster.id
  launch_type     = "EC2"
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.sample_ecs_task_definition.arn
  desired_count   = 1
  network_configuration  {
    subnets         = [var.subnet_id]
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_capacity_provider" "sample-ecs-capacity-provider" {
  name = "sample-ecs-capacity-provider"

  auto_scaling_group_provider {
    auto_scaling_group_arn         = aws_autoscaling_group.sample_asg.arn
    managed_scaling {
      maximum_scaling_step_size = 1000
      minimum_scaling_step_size = 1
      status                    = "ENABLED"
      target_capacity           = 10
    }
  }
```

Comment: Start by logging on to one of the EC2 instances and checking the ECS Agent Log at `/var/log/ecs/ecs-agent.log`

Answer (score 0):

Is ECS agent is installed in your EC2?? Is your EC2 have  internet access??